# Spring - same mapping to display different list

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to use the same view to display different lists based on the param I'm passing from the button in JSP.

what I need is: when user click on button, will call the same view but data should be display from the second list .(getPreviousYearReports())

here's my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewReports.do", method = {RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView viewReports( @RequestParam final Integer storeNumber,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView view = getModelAndView("viewReports");

    List<StoreReport> reportsList;
    if(request.getParameter("previous") != null ) {
        reportsList = storeReportService.getPreviousYearReports(storeNumber);

    } else {
        reportsList = storeReportService.getReportsByStore(storeNumber);
    }
....
}
```

in my JSP. 
I have added submit button to call the same view mapping

```
<button id="previous" name="previous" type="submit" class="btnFwd gradient smButtonStyling"
    onClick="window.location.href='/viewReports.do?storeNumber=${storeNumber}'">
View Previous Year Reports
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing to pass the "&previous" param

```
<button id="previous" name="previous" type="submit" class="btnFwd gradient smButtonStyling"
        onClick="window.location.href='/StoreReports/viewReports.do?storeNumber=${storeNumber}&previous'">
      View Previous Year Reports
</button>
```